# Like command not working in mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-like

When I remove the firstcomm Like `%?%`, it works. When I leave it in, it fails to bring back a result (although no actual errors from the script). And yes, `firstcomm` is apart of my database. So why is this? Am I doing `%?%` wrong?

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);
   $sql = 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE firstcomm LIKE %?% AND ...';
$params = array( $qu, ... );

$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$q->execute( $params );
$doc = new DOMDocument();
```

Update: This also fails...

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);
   $sql = 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE firstcomm LIKE ? AND ...';
$params = array( $qu, ... );

$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$q->execute( $params );
$doc = new DOMDocument();
```

Comment: Try `LIKE ?` and value with `'%?%'` if it is a prepared statement.

Comment: the `%?%` must be quoted... you've got a syntax error as you've written it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE firstcomm LIKE '%?%' AND ...";
```

Comment: The rest of the code actually works on its own. It's this specific part that throws it.

Comment: how do u bind the params?

Comment: params array info also needed, in fact, is the key to see what happens

Comment: You need to bind params first and then execute the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE firstcomm LIKE ? AND ...';
$like = '%?%';
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $like);
$stmt->execute();
```